# Java: Accessing an ArrayList inside an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

In FleetTUI.java I have a list of Fleets (Each fleet will hold its own list of Trucks).

```
private static ArrayList<Fleet> fleetCollection;
```

In Fleet.java, I have a list of Truck objects.

```
ArrayList<Truck> fleetList;
```

which gets initialized in it's constructor.

```
    public Fleet(String businessName){
    this.businessName = businessName;
    this.fleetList = new ArrayList<Truck>();
}
```

So every time I make a new fleet, I am also making a list of Trucks along with it.

In FleetTUI.java, I have a method that adds a truck to a Fleet, made prior:

```
    public static void addTruck(){
    printFleets();
    System.out.println("Please enter the fleet number where this truck will be added:");
    inputText = scan.nextLine();
    int inputFleetId = Integer.parseInt(inputText);
    System.out.println("Please enter the truck's horn sound:");
    inputText = scan.nextLine();
    String inputHorn = inputText;
    System.out.println("Please enter the truck's fuel capactity:");
    inputText = scan.nextLine();
    int inputFuelCapacity = Integer.parseInt(inputText);
    System.out.println("Please enter the amount of gas remaining in the tank:");
    double inputGasRemaining = Double.parseDouble(scan.nextLine());
    **Fleet.fleetList**.add(inputFleetId, new Truck(inputHorn, inputFuelCapacity, inputGasRemaining));
    System.out.println("--- A truck that goes " + inputHorn + " with " + inputGasRemaining + " gallon(s) in a " + inputFuelCapacity + " gallon tank has been added to " + **fleetCollection.getBusinessName()** + "'s fleet ---" );
    System.out.println("");
}
```

I have bolded where I am getting errors.
The errors are:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field Fleet.fleetList
>
> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getBusinessName() from the type Fleet

I don't know any other way to access the list of trucks from inside the fleet I created with the method:

```
    public static void createFleet(){
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Please enter the name of the fleet.");
    inputText = scan.nextLine();
    
    fleetCollection.add(new Fleet(inputText));
    printFleets();
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("--- Fleet: " + inputText + " added ---");
    System.out.println("");
    
}
```

So I guess really, my question is:
How do I correctly add a new Truck into the list of Trucks, which is inside the Fleet I just made using createFleet(), which is housed in it's own collection of fleets?

**Update:** Thanks :) you guys really helped me! once again!

Comment: why is your method `addTruck()` static?

Comment: This looks like an initial poor design to me. static should be used with care and when relevant. My guess is that you should get rid of all your static keywords and instantiate objects properly. If tomorrown one ask you to handle several fleetCollections, your whole code has to refactored.

Comment: To avoid confusion rename your `fleetList` to `truckList`, that's what it represents.

Comment: @user1176922 please don't delete the question details with a "thank you" message. The details are important so that others understand the issue and the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are creating `static` methods within which you are then trying to access a `non-static` variable, in this case this being `fleetlist`. This will cause the error you are showing.

Since you are using a constructor and everything, you do not need to call the method `static`. Calling it static will allow the method to be called without the object needing to be constructed, which from what I am seeing is not something you are after.

So in short, make your methods non-static by removing the `static` keyword from the method declaration and access your methods such as `addTruck()` and `createFleet()` through the use of the initialized `Fleet` object.

On the other hand, you can declare your fleetlist to be static, like so:

```
private static ArrayList<Truck> fleetList;
```

EDIT: Seeing your comment, this is how you can do it:

In Java, it is considered good practice to encapsulate your object variables so that you can better control the access to such variable, so you can do something like so in your `Fleet` Class:

```
private List<Truck> fleetList;

public Fleet(String businessName){
    this.businessName = businessName;
    this.fleetList = new ArrayList<Truck>();
}

public List<Truck> getFleetList()
{
    return this.fleetList;
}
```

In your `FleetUI` Class you can do something like so:

```
private ArrayList<Fleet> fleetCollection;    
...   
for (Fleet fleet : this.fleetCollection)
{
    for (Truck truck : fleet.getFleetList())
    {
         //Do something with your truck here
    }
}
```

EDIT 2: To add a truck to your array, you can do it in 2 ways. Let us assume that the object `fleet` is the Fleet to which you want to add your truck. In your `FleetUI` class you can do like so:

`fleet.getFleetList().add(new Truck(...))`

The other (and in my opinion, better way) is to have an `addTruck` method in your `fleet` object like so:

```
public void addTruck(Truck truck)
{
    this.fleetList.add(truck);
}
```

Comment: @user1176922: I have modified my answer. Hope it makes things more clear to understand.

Comment: I have further improved my answer. Just as an FYI, the helper method encapsulates the field of the object. This encapsulation is one of the corner stones of OOP, and I would recommend you would learn to use it since it can be quite useful.

Comment: @user1176922: Yes, if you want you can do something like so: `for(Fleet fleet : fleetCollection){if (fleet.getName().equals("myFleet"){fleet.addTruck(new Truck(...));break;}}`. In this case I assumed that the `Fleet` object had a name and you wanted to find a fleet with a specific name. You can obviously swap in any other mechanism you want.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are calling

   Fleet.fleetList.add()

   method from the static method addTruck.
2. It is bad practice to reference a member like this:

   Fleet.fleetList.add

   you should introduce some accessor method to add a truck to a flletList in your
   Fleet class

Comment: as I said the problem is that the list is not static and you call its add method from static method addTruck.

Comment: I changed all my methods to non-static.

Comment: did it help the situation? :)

Comment: that is new one but the idea is the same you are calling non-static run from some static method in FleetUI

Comment: first create an instance of the class whose method you going to call in static code.

Comment: Doh. I need to create an instance.

Comment: First (ugly) option would be keep a reference to the Fleet instance and use it when u need to add the Trucks. The second , would be to change you design and make the Fleet accessible in O(1) by using HashMap<String,Fleet> (then your fleet going to need a String id and also equals() and hashcode() implemented)

Comment: Hmm. I may just let this problem lie until tomorrow. its 3 AM and my laptop is dying :(